# curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Tags: curl, certificates

I'm [installing Waydroid on Ubuntu](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops#ubuntu-debian-based-install-instructions), when running:

```
export DISTRO="focal" && \
sudo curl -# --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -Sf https://repo.waydro.id/waydroid.gpg --output /usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg && \
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg] https://repo.waydro.id/ $DISTRO main" > ~/waydroid.list && \
sudo mv ~/waydroid.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/waydroid.list && \
sudo apt update
```

I get the error:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:                        
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) and have fully updated  the system.

```
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119~20.04.2).
```

Comment: This issue and the solution are in https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/834  (go to CURL_CA_BUNDLE_AUTODETECT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem. What worked for me was updating the ca-certificates.

I first ran `cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and got this response:

> cat: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificats.crt: No such file or directory

Thus, there was no file for curl to use.

According to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html we can create a new ca-certificate. What I did was run `sudo update-ca-certificates` and afterward the 77 error went away.

I hope this helps. One note is that I am not very familiar with the `update-ca-certificates` command, and am unsure if there are some options that can be set to make this fix work better. Also, as is everything with info on the internet, use this at your own risk.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem and solved it like this:

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
$ sudo apt reinstall ca-certificates
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Somehow the certificate authority chain file got messed up, I guess.

Credits: https://bobcares.com/blog/curl-error-77-problem-with-the-ssl-ca-cert/

Comment: `sudo update-ca-certificates` allowed the installer to complete. I was a bit wary of running `rm f` (which I misread as `rm -rf`), but could have created a snapshot beforehand.

Comment: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt is a default location. It can happen that the .crt file is in another directory (wrong installation, different Linux distribution etc.). In such case the env variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE should be set to the custom location of the .crt file.
If this variable is set it also makes sense to check whether it points to an existing file.

Answer (score 2):

From the look of the error, you may not have the `ca-certificates` package installed. You can resolve the issue via Terminal like this:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

Once installed, you should be able to run your cURL request properly

Comment: `ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119~20.04.2).`

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/ssl/certs` directory? Are the permissions of all files set to `root:root`? 

Comment: Yes I do, all permissions appear to be `root root`

Comment: Silly question, but what are the permissions on the `certs` directory? The directory itself must have execute permissions in order for cURL and other tools to use it: `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: Sorry, should the command `drwxr-xr-x` be detected by bash on a standard Ubuntu installation (a fresh VM)?

Comment: It’s not a command, but the permission list for the directory. The list comes from a stock Ubuntu installation 

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this issue by using the [official Ubuntu Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) to generate a new ca-certificates.crt and copy it to my host machine. This is roughly how you could follow the same pattern:

```bash
$ docker pull ubuntu   # You might want to specify a version here
$ docker run --rm -it --name ubuntu-docker docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest bash
root@3a5c34437949:/$ apt update && apt install -y curl
root@3a5c34437949:/$ curl http://echo.jsontest.com/it/works
{"it": "works"}
```

Then in a separate window or tab while container is still running:

```bash
$ cp /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt ~  # Backup just in case
$ docker cp ubuntu-docker:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

From this point curl started working immediately. The installation or reinstallation of ca-certificates DID NOT work for me. I had recently dabbled with adding a custom certificate into the chain and I might've hosed the file. I'm guessing Ubuntu never overwrote it because it didn't want to clobber my changes.

**Update:**

While the above did work for me it was really just a temporary fix and any refresh of my ca-certificates would bring the issue back. Apparently I forgot that I copied a custom certificate file into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and it kept getting appended to my `ca-certificates.crt`. That on it's own isn't bad, but that particular cert file wasn't in PEM format, which is what ca-certificates requires.

In short, be careful what you copy into those ca-certificates folders.

Comment: Don't know why but running `sudo update-ca-certificates` at any time will "hose" the file again. Extremely frustrating.

Comment: Narrowed down the reason for my curl failure. The very last certificate in my `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` must be corrupt or something. I remove that cert and everything is fine. Oddly that cert (and only that one) has carriage returns after it. Removing the carriage returns doesn't help. I also can't find that cert in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/` (I found every other cert I've searched for).

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error when run **composer update**
And I tried all the commands to reinstall the cert file, but the problem was not solved.

***I realized that the error is due to permission***
So the problem was solved with this command

```
cd /etc/ssl

sudo chmod 755 -R certs/
```